# SQL Stored procedure- Must declare the scalar variable "@user_name"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am getting the following error while I execute it.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@user_name".

(1 row(s) affected)

```
USE [qcsl]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UserAdvancedSearch]    Script Date: 3/31/2017 12:09:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserAdvancedSearch]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (
    @user_name varchar(50) = NULL,
    @role_id int = 2,
    @user_status int = 1



    )
    AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @query varchar(2000);
SET @query = 'select * from user_main
where (CONCAT(user_first_name,user_last_name) like  CONCAT(@user_name) OR CONCAT(CONCAT(user_first_name,user_last_name) IS NULL)
AND
(user_role_id_ref=@role_id OR user_role_id_ref IS NULL)
AND
(user_status = @user_status OR user_status IS NULL)';
EXEC(@query)
END
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql for this?

Comment: I did not get you ??

Comment: tried to execute your sp and there's nothing wrong with it

Comment: i dont think you should have parameters with default values.. instead, in your query, you should add `ISNULL(parameter_here, default_value)`. or if  that parameters are constants, dont put them as parameters but as variables.

Comment: Zohar is pointing out that you're currently building a *string* and then calling `EXEC` on it for no apparent reason - you could just have the query in that string appearing directly inside the stored procedure.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever couldn't have put it better myself, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have parameters in dynamic query so modify your execute query like below and try.

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query,N' @user_name varchar(50),@role_id  INT,@user_status int',@user_name=@user_name,@role_id=@role_id,@user_status=user_status
```

Also, modify your line of code

```
DECLARE @query varchar(2000);
```

to

`DECLARE @query nvarchar(2000);`

Comment: It's showing me.Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: yes you are correct. i just noticed that you have declared your dynamic query variable as varchar rather it should be nvarchar. I have edited my answer to resolve your current error,hope this will help you.